# JAVA - Having trouble checking if a user input date is right

Tags: java, validation

I have two classes, Main1 and a date (my own defined date class). I am trying to get user input of day, month and year, and then trying to check if this is a valid date using my date class. Im really confused and not sure if this is right way.

Heres the code for Main1 class:

```
public class Main1 {
public static void main(String[] args){     
    int myDay = 0, myMonth = 0, myYear = 0;
    boolean dataCorrect = false;
    date travelDate; // travelDate will hold the date entered
    do {
        try {
            do {
                myDay = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the day: "));
                myMonth = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the month: "));
                myYear = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the year: "));                   
                travelDate = new date(myDay,myMonth,myYear);                    
            } while (travelDate.checkInputs(travelDate.formDate()) == false); // keeps looping until the date entered is correct                    
            dataCorrect = true;                 
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error! Enter a correct date");
        }
    } while (dataCorrect == false); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, myDay + "-" + myMonth + "-" + myYear);
}
```

}

This is code for my own defined date class:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class date {
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
private String userTravel;

// Constructor 
public date(int d, int m, int y) {
    setDate(d,m,y);     
}

// Methods
public void setDate(int d, int m, int y) {
    setDay(d);
    setMonth(m);
    setYear(y);
}

public String formDate() {
    userTravel = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
    return userTravel;
}

public boolean checkInputs(String inDate) {
    if (inDate == null)
      return false;
    //set the format to use as a constructor argument
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    if (inDate.trim().length() != dateFormat.toPattern().length())
      return false;

    dateFormat.setLenient(false);

    try {
      //parse the inDate parameter
      dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
    }
    catch (ParseException pe) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void setDay(int d) {
    day = d;
}

public void setMonth(int m) {
    month = m; 
}

public void setYear(int y) {
    year = y; 
}
```

I am also unsure if the code for the method checkInputs is right.

EDIT: I have removed the IF statement as stated below in answers, Thank You.
Just wanted to ask if there is anyway i can enforce the user to enter a four digit year YYYY always or it will keep looping until this happens

Comment: So what is actually going wrong?  What are you expecting?

Comment: Whenever I run this, it's stuck infinite loop asking me for day, month and year. I am expecting it to validate a date and then just output it to screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to check the input date `String` length against the date format pattern:

```
if (inDate.trim().length() != dateFormat.toPattern().length())
   return false;
```

For example, you can have an input date of `2-3-2013` but your pattern is `dd-MM-yyyy` so the lengths of these 2 `Strings` won't match, returning `false` from `checkInputs` keeping you in the loop. Of course dates such as `10-12-2013` won't cause an infinite loop.

Just parsing using `SimpleDateFormat`, in its own, can provide the necessary validation you need.

Comment: Thank you, I removed that if statement and it now seems to work.

Comment: Consider also [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html)...

Comment: That seems a pretty neat feature, but I think for this code I will be tested on my error handling/trapping features. I think ill keep it as it is. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The method *checkInputs* fails in this part:

```
if (inDate.trim().length() != dateFormat.toPattern().length())
  return false;
```

In cases where the day or month integer doesn't have two digits (like 1,2,3.. ,9), the length of the inDate won't be equal to the pattern length. For example, the date date 1-1-2013 has 8 characters,while the pattern expects 10.

I believe that if you remove this condition, the code will work as you expect.

Comment: Yeh thank you, it seems to work now. Can I ask, is there any way I can enforce the user to enter a four digit year yyyy?

Comment: There is no way using the JOptionPane input dialog. You should use a swing masked input.